# Are all nilpotent groups hamiltonian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, nilpotent-groups

Are all nilpotent groups hamiltonian? That is, is every subgroup of a nilpotent group normal?

I don't think so. Every Sylow subgroup of nilpotent group is normal and every nilpotent group is a direct product of its Sylow subgroups. But, are they hamiltonian?

And, would the converse be true? That is, is every hamiltonian group nilpotent? Any small counterexamples? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: For the first question, check by hand the dihedral group of order $2^n\ge 8$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to what has been answered: a subgroup $H$ of $G$ is called *subnormal* if there exists a series of subgroups $H=H_0 \lhd H_1 \lhd \cdots \lhd H_s=G$. A normal subgroup is obviously subnormal, but the converse is not true. Now, finite nilpotent groups are exaclty the finite groups in which every subgroup is subnormal. For a proof: see for example M.I. Isaacs, *Finite Group Theory*, Lemma 2.1.

Answer (score 4):

A *finite* group $G$ is hamiltonian if and only if $G\cong Q_8\times A\times B$, where $A$ is an abelian group with odd order and $B$ is a direct product of $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Example: every $p$-group is nilpotent but it is not hamiltonian in general.

Conversely, a *finite* group is nilpotent if and only if it is a direct product of Sylow subgroups. Hence if a group is hamiltonian, all of its Sylow subgroups are normal. Hence it is a direct product of Sylow subgroups.

Comment: How could we prove that if a group is hamiltonian, it can be written as $Q_8\times A\times B$?

Comment: Try googling "Hamiltonian Groups". The first five links or so all give references to proofs.